# Master & Node Setting not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to configure 1 Master and 1 data node on my Cluster.I have done following changes on my config file:

```
Master Config:

 index.number_of_shards: 5
 index.number_of_replicas: 1

 node.master: true 
 node.data: false
cluster:
name: ES-Testing

node:
name: master # in our case this is set to the host IP with Chef

discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["170.30.10.16"]


#threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000
script.disable_dynamic: false
#indices.store.throttle.type: none
#index.merge.policy.reclaim_deletes_weight: 3.0
#index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once: 5
#index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier: 5
cluster.routing.operation.hash.type:          org.elasticsearch.plugin.direct.DirectRoutingHash  
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 40%
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

Node conf:

index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1

node.master: false
node.data: true
cluster:
name: ES-Testing

node: 
name: node # in our case this is set to the host IP with Chef

discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["170.30.10.16"]


#threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000
script.disable_dynamic: false
#indices.store.throttle.type: none
#index.merge.policy.reclaim_deletes_weight: 3.0
#index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once: 5
#index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier: 5 
cluster.routing.operation.hash.type: org.elasticsearch.plugin.direct.DirectRoutingHash
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 40%
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

When i restart my es on both master and node & run command

```
  Curl '<my_ip>:9200'
```

In  case of master it show expected result status:200 but in case of node 
in gives me status:503 Error.

Here is my log file of node:

```
   [2016-03-16 09:46:50,934][INFO ][node                     ] [node] stopping ...
   [2016-03-16 09:47:12,723][INFO ][node                     ] [node] version[1.7.1], pid[9504], build[b88f43f/2015-07-29T09:54:16Z]
   [2016-03-16 09:47:12,724][INFO ][node                     ] [node] initializing ...
   [2016-03-16 09:47:12,838][INFO ][plugins                  ] [node] loaded [elasticsearch-direct-routing-plugin], sites [HQ]
   [2016-03-16 09:47:12,877][INFO ][env                      ] [node] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [43.3gb], net total_space [49.2gb], types [ext3]
   [2016-03-16 09:47:15,940][INFO ][node                     ] [node] initialized
   [2016-03-16 09:47:15,940][INFO ][node                     ] [node] starting ...
   [2016-03-16 09:47:16,040][INFO ][transport                ] [node] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/172.31.12.17:9300]}
   [2016-03-16 09:47:16,049][INFO ][discovery                ] [node] ES-Testing/ryRsicZLRR2qupBAoUY2rQ
   [2016-03-16 09:47:46,049][WARN ][discovery                ] [node] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
   [2016-03-16 09:47:46,054][INFO ][http                     ] [node] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/172.31.12.17:9200]}
   [2016-03-16 09:47:46,054][INFO ][node                     ] [node] started
```

If i am doing something wrong please let me know.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please stop posting updates as *answers* to your question. The "answer" field below is reserved for people posting actual answers. If you have new information, edit it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your master node configuration you need to set this

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["170.30.10.17"]
```

Otherwise your master will never be able to discover the data node.

The best is to always list all nodes so it's easier to deploy your configurations.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["170.30.10.16", "170.30.10.17"]
```

Also you probably need to set `network.host: <ip_of_host>` in each configuration file to make sure each node binds to an IP address that the other node can see.

**UPDATE**

One missing info in the question was that those two hosts are on EC2 and thus:

- the cloud-aws plugin is required and needs to be configured

  - `cloud.aws.xyz` (i.e. `region`, `access_key`, `secret_key`)
  - `discovery.type: ec2`
- `network.host` can be set to `_ec2_`
- `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` can be commented out as it's not needed

Comment: Thanks I have done as per your suggestion.But my node is still showing status:503.    In network.host setting i have set In my master Node Ip and vice versa.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current start up logs from your data node?

Comment: please help me out i am working on it since morning.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've set `network.host: <ip_of_host>` in your configuration files.

Comment: master Ip: 170.30.10.16, Node Ip: 170.30.10.17   In master config i have  set network.host: 170.30.10.17 & vice versa. Is i am doing it in a right manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106455/discussion-between-kk0608-and-val).

Comment: yeahhhh val i have done it...and it cant be possible without your support.

Comment: What do you mean? You've configured the AWS settings and then what happened?

Comment: No i have done it without AWS setting..Its was my fault it created .swp file thats why it is electing both as master.

Comment: So this answer didn't help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Now m getting these error.

[cluster.service          ] [master] detected_master [172.31.12.16][Rbi6kBUcT4C8fXuuqsKKzQ][ip-172-31-12-16.ec2.internal][inet[/172.31.12.16:9300]]{data=false, master=true}, added {[172.31.12.16][Rbi6kBUcT4C8fXuuqsKKzQ][ip-172-31-12-16.ec2.internal][inet[/172.31.12.16:9300]]{data=false, master=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[172.31.12.16][Rbi6kBUcT4C8fXuuqsKKzQ][ip-172-31-12-16.ec2.internal][inet[/172.31.12.16:9300]]{data=false, master=true}])
[2016-03-17 07:22:10,051][INFO ][http                     ] [master] bound_address {inet[/172.31.12.16:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/172.31.12.16:9201]}
[2016-03-17 07:22:10,052][INFO ][node                     ] [master] started